# Jenkins pipeline ssh agent git push failes

Tags: git, jenkins

In my jenkins pipeline I can clone the repository fine, but using SSH Agent plugin to push back a tag fail. I've made sure that the deploy key at github has write access, so there seems to be some other problem...

```
pipeline {
   agent { docker { image 'node:8' } }

   stages {
      stage('Pull Repo') {
          steps {
            git (
                branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: 'cred-id',
                url: 'github.com:***'
            )
            sshagent(['github-omnia']) {
                sh("git tag -a \"release-2.3.${BUILD_NUMBER}\" -m \"Jenkins built ${BUILD_NUMBER}\"")
                sh("git push --tags")
            }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit:**
Here's the console output for the error

```
[ssh-agent] Using credentials git (Access to Github-**)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ docker exec a6cee721d592b10bb94abbde0471d24a4320dcd07362affb1f18454d6ebe028d ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-TI7dNVoYszsC/agent.12
SSH_AGENT_PID=17
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
Identity added: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Build-And-Deploy-***@tmp/private_key_7884642190516796613.key (/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Build-And-Deploy-***@tmp/private_key_7884642190516796613.key)
[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ git config --global user.email jenkins@***.se
[Pipeline] sh
+ git config --global user.name Jenkins
[Pipeline] sh
+ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:***/***
[Pipeline] sh
+ git tag -a release-2.3.3 -m Jenkins built 3
[Pipeline] sh
+ git push origin --tags
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Please include the error message so we can get an idea what might be wrong. The error _may_ be in your Jenkinsfile, but it may just as well be related to some problem with your Jenkins set up or network environment.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sure, I've edited the question with console output. Host key verification failed seems pretty straight forward. But as I said - it manages to pull just fine in the step above. My guess is that ssh-agent for some reason uses a bad key.

Comment: There we go. The error message is "Host key verification failed." Git tries to push with the SSH protocol, which in turn verifies the host key of the server upon connection. The _easy_ way to make this work is to set the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"`, which will simply disable host key checks, thereby potentially allowing monster-in-the-middle attacks. The _right_ way to fix this depends on more context than I'm willing to learn about your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for a way to do this without ignoring host verification entirely, and without modifying my Jenkins machine's `known_hosts` since I want to use docker. I ended up with something like this:

1. In Jenkins, create a new credential of type "Secret text" (let's call it `GITHUB_HOST_KEY`), and set its value to be the host key, e.g.:

```sh
# gets the host for github and copies it. You can run this from
# any computer that has access to github.com (or whatever your
# git server is)
ssh-keyscan github.com | clip
```

2. In your Jenkinsfile, save the string to `known_hosts` before using `sshagent`. Here's my pipeline; it takes a branch called `master-v5` and generates a branch `master-v5-dist` which contains a number of build files.

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'node:14' } }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master-v5',
                    url: 'git@github.com:internetarchive/bookreader.git',
                    credentialsId: 'YOUR_GH_CREDENTIALS'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') { steps { sh 'npm install && npm run build' } }
        stage('Push') {
            steps {
                sh 'git config user.email "foo@bar.com"'
                sh 'git config user.name "Mr. Foo Bar"'
                
                sh 'git add BookReader'
                sh 'git commit -m Build files [ci skip]'

                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'GITHUB_HOST_KEY', variable: 'GITHUB_HOST_KEY')]) {
                    sh 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && echo "$GITHUB_HOST_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
                }
                sshagent (credentials: ['YOUR_GH_CREDENTIALS']) {
                    sh 'git push -f origin HEAD:master-v5-dist'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures you're using a trusted host key, since you got the host key (presumably) at a time when you were certain you were connected to the real github.com .

Comment: Even though this is not the exact answer to the question I had (so many years ago) I'll still mark it as correct as this seems to be a good way of doing this.

Comment: I have not logged in in six years. I did this only to say thank you for this response.